# Remove month from Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a query that does the following:

Sums up the total clients before a conversion to new software and compares that to clients after conversion to new software.  What I would like to do is throw out the conversion month from the data.
I have the following columns:

```
NewClients, ConversionDate, ComparisonMonths
```

Using Dateadd I can have the following formulas:

```
PriorClients = Sum of New Clients
Between Dateadd(mm, -ComparisonMonths, ConversionDate) and ConversionDAte

AfterClients = Sum of New Clients
Between ConversionDate and DAteadd(mm, ComparisonMonths, ConversionDate)
```

The challenge is that the conversion date changes with each row as does the comparison months.  For example if the Conversion date is 10/12/2013 I want the following:

```
PriorClients = Sum of New Clients
Between Dateadd(mm, -ComparisonMOnths, 'last day of month prior to conversionDate')
    and 'last day of month prior to conversiondate'
```

This has been simplified to ask the question.

Comment: I recommend (1) giving your table a name (anonymous tables are the bane of SQL questions), and (2) showing some sample data (input) and the expected result (output), commenting on any issues not covered by the sample (but it is better to illustrate).  I have a feeling you've over-simplified the schema; I can't see how you get multiple rows to work with when each row has a different date range attached.  It feels like you must have two tables (so we need two table names and two sets of data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://stevestedman.com/2012/10/tsql-rounding-datetime-to-nearest-seconds/) is an excellent article on rounding dates in MS SQL.  In your case, you want to round to the month. Expanding on the article:

```
declare @dtVariable as datetime;
set @dtVariable = getdate();

select @dtVariable as Original,
       DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, @dtVariable), 0) as FirstDayOfMonth,
       DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD( MONTH, 1, DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, @dtVariable), 0))) as LastDayOfMonth;
```

From here it should be simple to adjust your query to exclude the month by either adding a NOT BETWEEN or simply adjusting your start and parameters to the properly calculate months.